# find 200 digit prime numbers using BigInteger

Tags: java, math, kotlin, primes, prime-factoring

One way to do this which absolutely works is starting from 0 up to where you'll find 200 digit prime numbers.In order to do that I wrote this method:

```
var primeList = arrayListOf(BigInteger("2"))
fun findNextPrime(num : BigInteger): BigInteger {
    val n = num + BigInteger.ONE
    val sqrt = sqrt(num)
    for (bigInteger in primeList) {
        if(bigInteger > sqrt){
            return n
        }
        if(n % bigInteger == BigInteger.ZERO){
            return findNextPrime(num + BigInteger.ONE)
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

I add the numbers I find to primeList and check only the numbers less than squareRoot.Even though this was the fastest algorithm I could write but it takes so long after finding a million digits.which is only 7 digits.I'll probably die till it goes to 200 digits.(even though my laptop is i7 8th generation).So the next thing I used was this:

```
n = 2 * 3 * 5 *... + 1
```

well n is prime and it's pretty fast to use this method to get to high digits,but there's nothing for sure to get to 200 digits exactly.I got to 198 and 201 digits.But no 200 the code is simple but I post it anyway:

```
var all = BigInteger.ONE
primeList.forEach {
   all *= it
}
all++
println(all.toString().length)
```

Comment: btw `all += all * it` does not compute the product of the primeList

Comment: https://gist.github.com/domnikl/6ad30f0a6ca3228f44e8273c08dbd879

you can change the code for big integer.

Comment: there is a concept of sequence in kotlin. you should look into it. Also the 200th price is 1217 which is not that big so you can just use integer.

Comment: `well n is prime` ? That isn't true in general. Not all [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) differ by 1 from a prime. To get a prime that is 200 digits long, the only feasible way is to generate random odd numbers of that size and test them for primality. In other words -- fish for them

Comment: I just ran the Miller-Rabin test on the two primorial prime candidates which straddle 200 digits. Both are composite numbers.

Comment: harold : that's in a foreach loop.so I'm sure it does.
Rahul : not the 200th I meant a 200 digit number.

Comment: @RahulKumar please explain filter and yeild in thaat gist code it's amazing still haven't tried it with bigInteger but it looks great honestly.

Comment: @stevemoretz products don't have addition in them, just multiplication

Comment: @harold You are totally right.I'm a little off today.all *= it meant to write this actually.

Comment: @RahulKumar The gist works fine but not for 200 digits I made it work with BigInteger but it's again too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't true that 1 + the product of the first `n` primes is always prime. You are possibly misremebering its role in the proof that there are infinitely many primes. It *is* true that if `p_1, p_2, ..., p_n` are the first `n` primes then

```
p_1 * p_2 * ... * p_n + 1
```

is either prime or contains a prime factor which is larger than any of those `p_i`, but this is consistent with the number being composite. See the Wikipedia article on [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for more information.

In the case of trying for 200 digits, the product of the first 92 primes + 1 has 199 digits and the product of the first 93 primes + 1 has 201 digits. In both cases, the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) shows that they are composite. I haven't been able to factor the 199 digit one, but the 201 digit one factors as

```
509558935064289364432032169616857776489168568369134671296055828054188240764364761921821351373922822013621199759688858354748131233614846920025560717744496960296617420071391914813530238313960697008021211 = 11587 * 43976778723076669062918112506848863078378231498156094873224806080451216083918595142989673890905568483094951217717170825472351016968572272376418461874902646094469441621765074205016849772500275913353
```

With numbers of this magnitude, the only effective way to get a prime is to randomly generate a candidate number of the target size and test it for primality (using something like the Miller-Rabin test). By the prime number theorem, 200 digit primes are relatively plentiful, so in practice you can find such a prime very rapidly. For example, a Python script I wrote using Miller-Rabin spit out the following 200 digit prime in less than a second:

```
49675218696612399034240799519655205503986657506787162015105425670413948962864456158664793804627084299081036134562339483478437262146378569515417671690110863951848724044479367633926630234074394356492223
```

**On Edit**: Here is the Python script that I used to find a 200 digit prime. The code was for a class I was teaching in cryptography, so I wrote it to be easy to discuss rather than concise or efficient:

```
import random

#The following function finds s and d in
#n-1 = 2^s*d with d odd
def findSD(n):
    s = 0
    d = n-1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s = s + 1
        d = d//2
    return s,d

def checkBase(a,n):
    s,d = findSD(n)
    x = pow(a,d,n)
    if x == 1 or x == n-1:
        return "probable prime"
    else:
        for i in range(s-1):
            x = pow(x,2,n)
            if x == 1:
                return "composite"
            elif x == n-1:
                return "probable prime"
        #if you get to this stage, -1 not reached despite s-1
        #squarings -- so must be composite
        return "composite"

def MSR(n,k):
    #Implements the Miller-Selfridge-Rabin test for primality
    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randint(2,n-2)
        if checkBase(a,n) == "composite":
            return "composite"
    #if you get here n has survived k potential witnesses, so
    return "probable prime"

#The following function is slightly different from the one discussed in class:

def prime(n):
    smallPrimes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]

    for p in smallPrimes:
        if n == p:
            return True
        elif n % p == 0:
            return False

    if MSR(n,20) == "composite":
        return False
    else:
        return True

def findPrime(maxN):
    while True:
        m = random.randint(1,maxN//2)
        n = 2*m+1
        if prime(n):
            return n
```

For example, `findPrime(10**200)` will usually give you a 200-digit prime number (though getting a 199 digit or even smaller is possible).

Comment: I was told by a master of university that,that 3*5*7... always works.Looks like he's a bit off.Thanks for letting me know.And by the way even sharing your python code can help if you don't like kotlin or java :) so please post it thank you.

Comment: @stevemoretz I added the code. 3*5*7 ... + 1 is used as a way to show that there are arbitrarily large primes, so if you just remember that fact and haven't worked through the proof in a while, it is easy to see how the fine print that the number itself isn't necessarily prime might get lost.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by expression probable prime?Aren't we sure yet you mean by the end?

Comment: @stevemoretz The Miller Rabin test is probabilistic. It doesn't certify a number is prime, but can make the chance of a false positive arbitrarily low (lower than the probability of a hardware error in running a deterministic algorithm).

Comment: Thank you.It also looks like Miller Rabin is already a function in native java!I just don't really understand it.If you could explain it a little further and less complicating that would be great I'm just a programmer not in math major really.

Comment: @stevemoretz There is no easy way to explain [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). The text that I used last time I taught the class did a decent job of explaining the math: "Public Key Cryptography" by Lynn Batten. This book was meant mostly for programmers, so doesn't really make many background assumptions.

Comment: You know what you're right.Maybe it's just the python making it complicated for me.Because I'm not a python scripter normally.After writing the same thing in java it makes much more sense now.Thank you again I accepted your answer but will also add the method that does this in java by default.

Comment: Technically there are constructive methods like Maurer and Shawe-Taylor that produce proven primes, in addition to the usual methods involving selection+PRP testing.  It is also possible to do a general form primality proof on a 200 digit number quite rapidly (under 1 second), though people rarely bother.

Answer (score 3):

in BigInteger class there is a method called:

```
isProbablePrime(int)
```

it uses the same algorithm our friend used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55811399/10268067): 
But it also checks the result with another algorithm.It works quite neat.